# How to use mongodb change stream instead of periodic query?

Tags: mongodb

I wan't to calculate sum the documents in my collection satisfying a query. I dont want to poll my collection. How can you do this with mongodb changestream?

For example there are documents in the database and they all have some property: {"destination": "Target1"} And i want to know the amount of documents which are satisfying this previous requirement.

I don't want to run a query on every change of a collection. Because the documents changing very often

I am looking for a similar to [oracle's cqn](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/cqn.html#GUID-373BAF72-3E63-42FE-8BEA-8A2AEFBF1C35)

Comment: What kind of query? How do you want to use calculated sum?

Comment: For example there are documents in the database and they all have some property: {"destination": "Target1"}
And i want to know the amount of documents which are satisfying this previous requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use changestream and watch changes as follow:

```
watchCursor = db.getSiblingDB("mydatabase").mycollection.watch()

while (!watchCursor.isExhausted()){
   if (watchCursor.hasNext()){
    printjson(watchCursor.next());
  }
}
```

[changeStream docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/)

But perhaps you may do some query and use some good indexes?

It seems you can just execute:

```
   db.collection.count({destination:"Target1"})
```

and if you have index on "destination" field it will be pretty quick ...